# Place third float div at same level with first div

Tags: css, grid, floating

I have the next html strcture that I can't change it https://jsfiddle.net/fLjs43x7/ :

HTML:

```html
<div class="grid-parent">

  <div class="something">
    <div class="something-else">

      <div class="grid-100">
      </div>
      <!--- .grid-100 -->

      <div class="grid-60">
        1
      </div>
      <!-- .grid-60 -->

    </div>
    <!-- .something-else -->

    <div class="grid-60">
      2
    </div>
    <!-- .grid-60 -->
  </div>
  <!-- .something -->

  <div class="grid-30">
  </div>
  <!-- .grid-30 -->
</div>
<!-- .grid-parent -->
```

I want to place green div at same level with first blue div. How can I do this?  It's possible?

Thank you!

**I think I found a solution:**

I added

```
.something {
height: 1px;
overflow: visible;
}
```

And I change the middle float div:

```
.grid-606 {
display: inline-block;
float: none;
}
```

Here is the entire code: https://jsfiddle.net/fLjs43x7/2/

Answer (score 0):

I am using position property;
See this:--
hope it helps.

```css
.grid-parent {
  display: block;
  width: 1000px;
  height: 300px;
  position:relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  
  background-color: red;
}

.grid-30,
.grid-60,
.grid-100 {
  display: block;
  float: left;
  height: 50px;
  margin-left: 10px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}
.grid-100 {
  width: 1000px;
  background-color: yellow;
}

.grid-60 {
  width: 600px;
  background-color: blue;
}

.grid-30 {
  width: 300px;
  background-color: green;
  position:absolute;
  left:600px;
  top:60px;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid-parent">

  <div class="something">
    <div class="something-else">
    
      <div class="grid-100">
      </div> <!--- .grid-100 -->
      
      <div class="grid-60">
      1
      </div> <!-- .grid-60 -->
      
    </div> <!-- .something-else -->
    
    <div class="grid-60">
    2
    </div> <!-- .grid-60 -->
  </div> <!-- .something -->
  
  <div class="grid-30">
  </div> <!-- .grid-30 -->
</div> <!-- .grid-parent -->
```

Comment: I tried this, but in real code, the content within grid-100 is text and dynamic and I don't know the height of this. So I can't use position absolute because of top. Anyway, thanks ;)

Comment: Anytime :) @GheorghițăHurmuz

Comment: but if change of div order is not allowed, it doesn't seem to be possible , i guess

Comment: In the end I will try to change somehow